# Pixel perfect: положение не всех букв в строке совпадает

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, psd

При попытке наложить изначальный макет на свою вёрстку, столкнулась с проблемой, скрин которой прилагаю. Некоторые буквы совпадают, другие нет. Использовала letter-spacing и word-spacing. Пыталась использовать font-kerning. Есть ли какой-то способ выровнять буквы по макету?

[image: проблема]

Comment: Автор макета мог менять межбуквенное расстояние между любыми двумя буквами отдельно

Comment: Можно поместить каждую букву в отдельный `span` и выровнять стилями

Comment: Я чего- то не понимаю или расстояние в 1px между буквами это так важно?